# Mathematical induction

Tags: induction

[image]

I've already proven the first part but in (ii) I managed to get until

$u_{n+1} = \sqrt{9-\epsilon} - 1$

I don't know how to show the approximation answer.

Comment: What does $\approx$ mean precisely? $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{9-\varepsilon}-1}2=1\text{ and even }\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}((\sqrt{9-\varepsilon}-1)\ -\ 2)=0$$ So why can't I say $u_{n+1}\approx 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u_{n+1} = 3\sqrt{1-\dfrac{\epsilon}{9}} - 1 = 3\left(1-\dfrac{\epsilon}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} - 1\approx 3\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{9}\right)-1= 2-\dfrac{\epsilon}{6}$

Comment: I don't understand how you can approximate $3\left(1-\dfrac{\epsilon}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} - 1$   to   $3\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{9}\right)-1$

Comment: $(1+\epsilon)^{\alpha} \approx 1+\epsilon\cdot \alpha$

Comment: Is this a mathematical rule that can be applied in other similar situations? I'm confused because I've never seen this method.

Comment: This is popular in asymptotic calculus.